English U.S. indie Thriller Movie year 2006 -2010?
Hello it's been a long time since I've seen this movie but I'll do my best to describe it.
I'm looking for the name of a US English Indie Thriller Movie that came out approximately around 2006 to 2010. 
It's about a guy in his early 30's? who's life is in danger from the mob? And in order to get out of trouble he has to do all these dangerous different things around the city (I think New York) in a specific amount of time and the time that he has to complete it is actually the title of the movie. But anyways at the end of the movie he finds out that this whole thing was a prank for his birthday and he wasn't in any real danger.
Thanks hope that was enough information 

The Game (1997)

No, but thanks for trying to help.

"80 Minutes"
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1119178/
Full movie is on Youtube here (in French)
:



"Alex North has been injected with a poison inside his body and has only 80 minutes to find $15,000 for his boss Lloyd if he wants to live. Now he must go through the whole night, searching for ways to make up that amount."
Near the end, ca. at the 1:16:10 mark the curtain drops and it turns out it is a birthday prank.

Yes! Thanks so much.

You are welcome. You can select the answer above as Best Answer.
